# fwrite doubles the written content

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm trying to write a php variable inside another php file.

My writing content is:

```
$writeValue = "\$Var['".$this->js_checksum."'] = '".serialize($log_content)."';";
```

and I'm using Joomla `$stream->write($content);` to write this content into another php page.
The problem is that I'm getting, inside the php page after the writing process is done, double `$var`, identically, so basically the server writes the variable two times.
If I change `$writeValue = "a";` then the server is writing it only once, as it should.

I can't figure it out why?

Comment: Are you sure you are not in a loop and that the script isn't executed twice, for example via a doubled `include();` somewhere?

Comment: sure, not in a loop, in fact I just realize that serialize result is breaking the functionality...cause if I add $writeValue = "\$Var['".$this->js_checksum."'] = 'test';"; the script is working fine.
The serialized var contain, as key, a file path with / and \ so this might cause the problem.